# Pass function as argument in Go

Tags: function, go, wrapper

I've tried to create a function in Go that used to retry any fail query functions (usually because serialization issue).

```
func retryer(functionA func(interface{}) (interface{}, []error), maxRetry int, waitBetween time.Duration) interface{} {
    //when no error in functionA, retryer returns whatever functionA returns
    //when maxRetry is reached, returns nil
}
```

The functions I want to retry are looked like this

```
func GetTopStudent(classId string) ([]Student, []error) {
    //queries top 10 students for class with classId
}

func GetAverageStudentScores(classId string, from time.Time, until time.Time) ([]Pair, []error) {
    //queries all average score using aggregate, grouping by studentId
    //Pair behaves like C++ pair<string,string>
}
```

But, the results is a compile error

```
cannot use GetTopStudent (type func(string) ([]Student, []error)) as type func(interface{}) (interface {}, []error) in argument to retryer
```

I've tried to modify it a little and I got another compile error

```
cannot use GetTopStudent (type func(string) ([]Student, []error)) as type func(string) (interface {}, []error) in argument to retryer
```

Can anyone help me creating a general function to wrap a function to retry on error?

Comment: The signatures of the functions passed as a parameter must match the signature of the function type of the parameter exactly. You'll have to rewrite the functions you pass to take `interface{}`'s, and cast them to the appropriate types inside those functions.

Comment: That way, for N functions, I need N wrappers. I need the general function wrapper to greatly simplify me code.

Comment: Yes. Or redesign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to solve your problem would be to use closures.

For example, change the type of `retryer`:

```
func retryer(f func() error, maxRetry int, waitBetween time.Duration) error {
    // retry and wait logic
    err := f()
    // error handling, retry, and wait logic
    return err
}
```

Now call functions to be retried as:

```
// ...
classId := "some value"
// ...

var st []Student
var errors []error
err := retryer(func() error {
    st, errors = GetTopStudent(classId)
    // handle errors
    return nil
}, numTries, waitTime)
// use st here
```